# this size to use into malloc() is right?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Assuming that I have `char **` where each value of can have an `char *` and I need store more bytes to character teminator (`NULL`) how do I to compute this size? maybe..: `sizeof(char *) * strlen(src) + sizeof(NULL)` or only + 1 instead of `sizeof(NULL)`? I hope this is clear for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will all `char* src` have the same size ?

Comment: No, this is not clear.  Perhaps add some pseudo-code to illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: `sizeof(NULL)` makes no sense. `NULL` in C is just `0` and `sizeof(0)` is 4 or 8 which is overkill. Just use `+ 1`.

Comment: I think so. Actually, I am writing an split() implementation that in first parameter receive the delimiter and into second parameter the string for splited into tokens. For example: `char **
  split(const char * delimiteres, const char * src)
  {
   char ** out;
   char * token;

   out = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(src) + sizeof(NULL));
   assert(NULL != out);
   int size = 0; 
   
   for(token = strtok(strdup(src), delimiteres);
    NULL != token;
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiteres))
   {
    out[size] = token; `

Comment: @user834697: You should edit your question to include that code.

Comment: @Chris Well that depends, even though NULL does not have 'real' type, it is generally stored in pointer (and yointers on x86 are 4-8 byte).
@@user834697 assert(NULL != out); This looks just weird, why not use assert(out != NULL)? (perhaps matter of taste, but it probably increases readability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char **` is a pointer to a pointer to the first character of a string.  In your example, the memory for the pointer `char **out` is already allocated on the stack.  What you have to do is allocate the memory for the character array (C string) which `out` points to on the heap.  That is, you could do something like:

```
char **out;
char *str = malloc(strlen(src) * sizeof(char) + 1);
*out = str;
```

Now you can (for example) safely return `out` and pass control of the memory you allocated to the caller.

If you wanted to return a pointer to the first element of an array of strings (another way of interpreting a char **), you would have to first allocate on the heap enough memory for each string:

```
char **out = malloc(amount_of_strings * sizeof(char *));
// Repeat the following for each string in your array...
char *str = malloc(strlen(src) * sizeof(char) + 1);
out[index] = str;
```

Comment: No, a "pointer to a string" is a `char*`, not a `char**`.  Don't make the mistake of thinking that strings are pointers.  They're not.

Comment: How is `char *` a pointer to a string?  It is by definition a pointer to a character.  In C, a "string" is represented by a pointer to the first character in a contiguous block of memory.  Also, note that I edited out a small mistake in my above post, replacing `out = &str` with `*out = str`.  Oops.

Comment: It's a pointer to a string because that's how the C standard defines the phrase "pointer to a string".  See section 7.1.1 of the C standard ([latest draft here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)): "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character. ... A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character."

Comment: `char *str = (char *) malloc(strlen(src) * sizeof(char) + 1);` is better written `char *str = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);`.  `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition, and casting the result of `malloc()` is unnecessary and can mask errors in some cases.

Comment: Aha, I see, thanks!  I guess I've been doing too much C++ recently. :)  I've edited my answer, but I chose to leave the sizeof(char) in there to keep it explicit for those who are learning.